# Reading/writing multi-page image file with python

Tags: python, image, tiff

I want to grab images from a multipage image file (`.tiff` or `.gif`), process them, and save them to another multipage image file.

Although packages such as `imageio` or `cv2` do provide functions to handle multipage image, they load every frame on memory at once. Instead, I want to have a generator which yields each frame one by one to reduce memory usage.

Is there any package which allows it? Or how can I implement it myself? Thanks!

edit: I found out that Pillow provides `ImageSequence` iterator which can read `.tiff` and `.gif` file. However, writing multiframe image is still not supported...